# Difference between modifier and helper in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend

What is the difference between the modifier and the helper in ember js?

Example:

- helper `{{fn this.increment amount}}`
- modifier `{{on "click" this.increment}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A helper is "just a function" that can be invoked from templates. More information here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/

Since ember-source@4.5, helpers can be *any* function. For example

```js
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  double = (x) => {
    return x * 2;
  }

  // or pre ember-source@4.5
  // you'll need to import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';
  double = helper(([x]) => {
    return x * 2;
  })
}
```

```
{{this.double 10}}
^ renders 20
```

A modifier is a special function that only attaches to an element and is passed the element -- this is useful for wiring up add/remove eventListener stuff (or other behaviors).

More information on that (and the philosophy) here: https://github.com/ember-modifier/ember-modifier

Here is an example of defining a modifier for use in your component

```js
import { modifier } from 'ember-modifier';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  inView = modifier(element => {
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
    
    // do something with the IntersectionObserver

    return () => {
      //cleanup
      observer.disconnect();
    }

  });
}
```

```
<div {{this.inView}}>

</div>
```

details of [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) usage omitted for brevity.

---

now for the helper and modifier in your example:

`fn` - partially applies values to your function, similar to JS' bind.
it could be implemented this way:

```js
const fn = (passedFunction, ...args) => {
  return passedFunction.bind(?, ...args); 
}
```

there `?` is whatever the context the function originally had was (the `this`)

`on` is a shorthand for both addEventListener, and removeEventListener.
It could be implemented like this:

```js
const on = modifier((element, [eventName, handlerFunction]) => {
  element.addEventListener(eventName, handlerFunction);

  // cleanup
  return () => element.removeEventListener(eventName, handlerFunction);
});
```

Comment: can we define the helper function inside a component file?

Comment: absolutely, yea. the first code snippet does exactly that